# Hi, I took a Python algorithm Question concerning 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm struggling with solving a Python programming question concerning 2-dimensional arrays.
First of all, 19*19 sized arrays are assigned. Then the number of coordinates are assigned, which is followed by coordinates' exact values which are to be assigned.
for example,

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2
10 10
12 12
```

What two coordinates do is to change values on x and y axes which are meeting in an assigned value from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0.
Accordingly, the upper example returns the result below.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The code I made for this algorithm is this.

```
d = []
for i in range(1, 20):
    d.append(input().split())

n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    x, y = map(int, input().split())
    x, y = x-1, y-1
    for j in range(1, 20):
        if d[j - 1][int(y)] == 0:
            d[j - 1][int(y)] = 1
        else:
            d[j - 1][int(y)] = 0

        if d[int(x)][j - 1] == 0:
            d[int(x)][j - 1] = 1
        else:
            d[int(x)][j - 1] = 0

for i in range(1, 20):
    for j in range(1, 20):
        print(d[i - 1][j - 1], end=' ')
    print()
```

However when below values are assigned, a result becomes to be incorrect.
Below is the assigned values which make my code return a wrong result.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2
1 1
19 19
```

Below is what my code returns which is a wrong answer.

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

But what a right answer should be is same to below.

```
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

I've been struggling for over an hour but I still don't get what's wrong to my code.
Thank you for reading my question and I'm expecting you to advice me in a right way.

Comment: None of the values in your array will ever be equal to `0` - they're strings, so the values they might have are `"0"` or `"1"`.

Comment: And if you ever change your matrix to be 1s and 0s, you can use `d[..][..] ^= 1` to change 0s to 1s and 1s to 0s, without needing an "if" statement.

Comment: Try with a smaller matrix. Also, use a debugger to step through the code. For that, there are video tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution minus the input feature. You might have to adapt the variables to best suit your needs.

```
# array is the 19x19 array
# change is the coordinates to change, namely [10, 10] and [12, 12]
# the +1 mod 2 simply flips the 0s and 1s

for c in change:
    for i in range(19):
        array[i][c[0]-1] = (array[i][c[0]-1]+1)%2
    for i in range(19):
        array[c[0]-1][i] = (array[c[0]-1][i]+1)%2
```

Comment: My problem was missing the data type of 0 and 1. It should have been string. Anyway thank you for the answer!